# System.UnauthorizedAccessException to create Folder using Asp.Net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, directory, create-directory

I am trying to create a folder using jQuery AJAX and ASP.Net.

```csharp
[WebMethod]
public void setCreateFolder(string dirLocation,string folderName)
{
  var folder = Server.MapPath(@dirLocation);
  if (!Directory.Exists(folderName))
  {
    Directory.CreateDirectory(folderName);
  }
  JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
  Context.Response.Write(js.Serialize("sucessfully created"));
}
```

```js
// Create Folder
$("#btnCreateFolder").click(function () {
  var dirPath = $('#ContentPlaceHolder1_txtPath_I').val();

  alert('calling path =' + dirPath);
  $.ajax({
    method: 'post',
    url: "GetAllFolderDetails.asmx/setCreateFolder",
    data: {
      dirLocation: dirPath,
      folderName: "TestName"
    },
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
      alert("Success");
    },
    error: function (result) {
      alert("Error");
    }
  });
});
```

When I click the button, it throws the following error message

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'TestName' is denied.

I check the folder properties, the Read-only attribute has a black dot. I tried to make it an empty checkbox and I apply and click ok, but when I open properties again, still that black check mark is there.

I am using windows 10. I check this [Microsoft link](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-files-winpc/unable-to-remove-read-only-property-of-folders/7f074765-ec49-4654-8419-e1bac6ce3950) also. But still the problem is same, I cannot remove the black dot

Comment: Is there a specific reason you need to create a physical folder on your webserver at runtime? That sounds like a really bad idea, not least of all for performance and scalability.

Comment: Duplicated ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16962587/system-unauthorizedaccessexception-on-iis7-5-full-control-everywhere